# How to fix an error Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Tags: python, selenium

I am using webdriver selenium. I'm encountering the following error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-25c7a5245744> in <module>()
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      3 driver.get("http://www.google.com")
      4 display.stop()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     96         count = 0
     97         while True:
---> 98             self.assert_process_still_running()
     99             if self.is_connectable():
    100                 break

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
    109             raise WebDriverException(
    110                 'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
--> 111                 % (self.path, return_code)
    112             )
    113 

WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

I used `chromium-browser version (70.0.3538.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)`, `selenium 3.141.0`, and `chromedriver version 2.43` .

I searched from many sources and realized the error is the chromium version. So, I tried installing latest version with `!sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser`

Nonetheless, it don't work on my google colab.

Please help me resolve it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Unlike using the FireFox webdriver, with chrome driver you have to indicate the path of the executable driver. Like this : webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')

Comment: PyOrion, no you don't.  you can call it with no args if it is in your path.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

For me, that's what the issue was. Typically `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` will install the snap too, but when it doesn't you have to manually install the snap.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') 
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
display.stop()
```

You will need to download the ChromeDriver executable from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/

Comment: I have downloaded `chromedriver 2.43`. However I see that `chromedriver 2.43` and `chrome 70.0.3538.77` that is compatible with each other
I'm encountering the same error when I experiment on windown
 
`Exception has occurred: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException
Message: chrome not reachable   (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) 
  File "C:\Users\luan1\Desktop\project10.py", line 33, in <module>
    driver.quit()`