# Selenium use chrome on Colab got unexpectedly exited

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory, chromium

I have been using selenium chromedriver in google colab for a while.
Today I start my work, I get the error never got before.
I'm wondering if this error is related to the chromedriver version.

---

#### This is install log today

```
!apt-get update
!apt install -y chromium-chromedriver


Get:1  focal-updates/main amd64 apparmor amd64 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1 [494 kB]
Get:2  focal/main amd64 liblzo2-2 amd64 2.10-2 [50.8 kB]
Get:3  focal-updates/main amd64 squashfs-tools amd64 1:4.4-1ubuntu0.3 [117 kB]
Get:4  focal-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.57.5+20.04ubuntu0.1 [37.6 MB]
Get:5  focal-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser amd64 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 [48.3 kB]
Get:6  focal-updates/universe amd64 chromium-chromedriver amd64 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 
...
...
(Reading database ... 129791 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
===> System doesn't have a working snapd, skipping
Unpacking chromium-browser (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package chromium-chromedriver.
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-chromedriver_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chromium-chromedriver (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up chromium-browser (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/chromium-browser to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/chromium-browser to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
Setting up chromium-chromedriver (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3) ...
```

---

#### This is install log yesterday

```
Get:1  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [1,159 kB]
Get:2  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser amd64 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [83.6 MB]
Get:3  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser-l10n all 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [5,230 kB]
Get:4  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-chromedriver amd64 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [5,594 kB]
...
...
Setting up chromium-chromedriver (108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) ...
Setting up chromium-browser-l10n (108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...
```

---

I found the colab system is updated to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04.
Is this the reason why chromedriver cannot be used?
How should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to execute Selenium? What's the Error Message?

Comment: Seems to me like a issue of snapd https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599467/20443541

Comment: same issue for me as well, till yesterday it was working fine

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii is the snapd work?

Comment: well dear friends i am also having issues on Colab with selenium

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These log messages...

```
Get:1  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [1,159 kB]
Get:2  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser amd64 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [83.6 MB]
Get:3  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser-l10n all 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [5,230 kB]
Get:4  bionic-updates/universe amd64 chromium-chromedriver amd64 108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 [5,594 kB]
...
...
Setting up chromium-chromedriver (108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) ...
Setting up chromium-browser-l10n (108.0.5359.71-0ubuntu0.18.04.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...
```

...is the result of an issue induced as the colab system is updated from `v18.04`  to ubuntu **`20.04 LTS`** recently.

---

### Quick Fix

> > `@mco-gh` created a new notebook following `@metrizable`'s guidance
> > (details below) which is working perfect as of now:
> > https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbEvuZOhkouYLda3RqiwtbM-o9hxGLyC

---

### Details

In the discussion [Issues when trying to use Chromedriver in Colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347) `@EvanWiederspan` clearly [mentioned](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1386349011):

> We recently upgraded the Ubuntu version, which may be causing this.
> After connecting to a runtime, can you try running "Use fallback
> runtime version" from the command palette (ctrl + shift + p)

`@metrizable` in his [comment](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1387453484) further clarified:

> I understand that you'd like to use selenium with chromium-browser
> under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Although YMMV, since Ubuntu 20.04+ no longer
> distributes chromium-browser outside of a snap package, you can
> install a compatible version from the Debian buster repository

Sample code:

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

# Install chromium and chromium-driver
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium chromium-driver

# Install selenium
pip install selenium
```

---

### Note

Generally the following line of code will install the snap too:

```
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

incase it doesn't you have to manually install the snap using:

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

Comment: You might format the sample code as a shell-codebox?

Comment: Also Note, that snap doesn't seem to work using colab.

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii I just transfer the debian.list and chromium.pref as file to google driver. when notebook start I copy these files to current path from my google driver. Then add keys and install chromedriver. It's works for me.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes imho (it was plagiated several times since being posted) -- this helped a lot of people using Colab && Selenium at work to keep doing their jobs. +1.

Comment: This did not work for me. I keep getting the same error. Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1 Can someone, please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this sample colab workbook to rebuild your script.
The reason is that the last Ubuntu update update supports chromium diver just via snap.

Post with explanation:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1397277515

Direct Link to Notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbEvuZOhkouYLda3RqiwtbM-o9hxGLyC

Comment: (Using Google Colab) It worked for me aswell but only after adding a line of code to the first cell in your notebook to remove chromium from Ubuntu first. (sudo apt remove chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

Answer (score 1):

After the runtime status says connected, open the command palette (ctrl + shift + p) and select "Use Fallback Runtime Version"

That should resolve this issue!

Reference:
https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1386349011

> We recently upgraded the Ubuntu version, which may be causing this. After connecting to a runtime, can you try running "Use fallback runtime version" from the command palette (ctrl + shift + p) and seeing if your notebook works after that?

Comment: Still same error in my case

Comment: can you share your code @kaliiiiiiiii ?

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is to do this first in addition to your usual thing you do in colab to make selenium work:

```
!sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta

!sudo apt remove chromium-browser
!sudo snap remove chromium

!sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Note: [Solution provided here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbEvuZOhkouYLda3RqiwtbM-o9hxGLyC) by @Johannes Stephan works but it crashes browser a lot and makes it unusable

FULL Code:

```
!sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
!sudo apt remove chromium-browser
!sudo snap remove chromium
!sudo apt install chromium-browser

!pip3 install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Could you provide a workbook example, please?

Comment: I have tried this solution and got this error: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6

Comment: comment updated with full code