# I cannot get webdriver to work on google colab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get install chromium chromium-driver
!pip3 install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "http://example.com/"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", options=options)
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Is the example of what I'm trying to run but it keeps saying: "Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1"

I've tried upgrading it python 3.9 and it didn't work.
I tried this:

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500
Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF
```

But this doesn't fix it as well and I keep getting the same error.

Is there even a way to fix this?

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75161366/service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-code-was-1) ?