# Webdriver error from Selenium on Google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, google-colaboratory

I'm creating a scraper on google colab using Selenium but now doesnt work. Yes in the past but I dont know why now doesn't.

The code is:

```
#dependencies
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install fake-useragent
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

#options to chromedriver
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent="'+userAgent+'"')
```

When a I run this code, colab show the next error:

"Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1"

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txamV.png)

Do you know any solution? I've looked for an answer on other related topics but nothing works for me

Run Selenium on Google Colab and scrape organic results

Comment: same problem as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited

Comment: This is a dublicate to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163200/20443541.
The solution is allready provided tho.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

...was the result of an issue induced as the colab system was updated from `v18.04` to ubuntu *`v20.04 LTS`* and with Ubuntu *`v20.04 LTS`* [google-colaboratory](/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory) no longer distributes **chromium-browser** outside of a snap package.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can install a compatible version of Chromium without snap following the discussion [How to install Chromium without snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap)

---

### Quick Fix

> > `@mco-gh` created a new notebook following `@metrizable`'s guidance
> > (details below) which is working perfect as of now:
> > https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cbEvuZOhkouYLda3RqiwtbM-o9hxGLyC

---

### Chromium Browser from Debian buster repository

However to install *`chromium-browser`* from the Debian buster repository using the following code block published by `@metrizable` in the discussion [Issues when trying to use Chromedriver in Colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3347#issuecomment-1387453484)

```
%%shell
# Ubuntu no longer distributes chromium-browser outside of snap
#
# Proposed solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/how-to-install-chromium-without-snap

# Add debian buster
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list <<'EOF'
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg] http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
EOF

# Add keys
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DCC9EFBF77E11517
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 112695A0E562B32A

apt-key export 77E11517 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster.gpg
apt-key export 22F3D138 | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-buster-updates.gpg
apt-key export E562B32A | gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/debian-security-buster.gpg

# Prefer debian repo for chromium* packages only
# Note the double-blank lines between entries
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/chromium.pref << 'EOF'
Package: *
Pin: release a=eoan
Pin-Priority: 500


Package: *
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 300


Package: chromium*
Pin: origin "deb.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 700
EOF

# Install chromium and chromium-driver
apt-get update
apt-get install chromium chromium-driver
```

Comment: But is this possible on Google Colab? Sorry I'm junior on dev

Comment: Definitely, it works. Problem solved, thanks!