# how to use selenium on google colab

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-colaboratory

background:
I'm using MacOS and because running selenium on Mac happened a lot of troubles, so I want to try running on google colab.

now:
I tried solutions answered few days ago but I can't even open a website.
[Webdriver error from Selenium on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75162162/webdriver-error-from-selenium-on-google-colab)

code:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!apt-get install -y chromium-browser
```

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver',options=options)
```

error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
    115         return_code = self.process.poll()
    116         if return_code:
--> 117             raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
    118 
    119     def is_connectable(self) -> bool:

WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Comment: is this `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver` correct path ? I think it should be  `/usr/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: @Akzy yeah it was correct in my colab environment. Also I tried your path and it came out the same error message.

Comment: Can you add the full error logs ?

Comment: @Akzy I renew the whole error message on the top

Comment: It could be because of different reason. Suggest you to checkout `https://stackoverflow.com/a/75164596/11863448`

Comment: What does !`ls /usr/lib/chromium-browser | grep chromedriver` give you?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii it shows chromedriver.