# WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

I want to run selenium in google colab i ran the following code:

```
    !apt update
    !apt install chromium-chromedriver
    !pip install selenium
    # set options to be headless, ..
    from selenium import webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    # open it, go to a website, and get results
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    wd.get("https://www.whoscored.com")
    print(wd.page_source)  # results`
```

the result expected is the page source being printed out instead i get this error in my notebook:

> WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Here is the link of the notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13oUHGDc6uy-4vJ1XnRdEcojoFoIToV75
i tried changing the webdriver to firefox but i get a different error memory related stuff:

> src/tcmalloc.cc:332] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x24680020c5d0

Comment: Dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium use chrome on Colab got unexpectedly exited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution from [Selenium use chrome on Colab got unexpectedly exited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited).
Looks like it was a runtime issue. Changing it and following the steps in the link helped and I executed the code there to fix the problem