# How do I run Selenium with a chromedriver on Colab?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory, google-chrome-headless

I've been through most Google results and stack answers about this. My problem is kind of strange, because even if I copy other's working code exactly onto my colab notebook I get the same WebDriverException. `WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1.`

I've tried many different combinations and since even otherwise functional code isn't working for me, I think I must be doing something wrong trivially. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

I can run it locally on a Jupyter notebook. Given this sample:

```
!pip install selenium 
!pip install webdriver_manager
!apt-get update 
!apt-get install -y chromium-browser 
!apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver_path = "usr/bin/chromedriver"

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path,options=options)
```

Error log:

```
<ipython-input-3-0dcd16366705>:10: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  chrome = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path,options=options)


WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
```

If I change it to a service object:

```
serv = ChromeService('usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service = serv, options=options)
```

Error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Any help or advice is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium use chrome on Colab got unexpectedly exited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited)

Comment: https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/issues/10#issuecomment-1387618009