# Running a script in Google Colab - throws back no results

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have issues running a tiny scraper in Google Colab. While we are able to run the code on Google Colab Notebooks, the real issue is that the clutch-page, we are trying to scrape is using CloudFlare, which can detect Selenium. There is a work-around now (see below)

So far so good: with the little code below we are able to scrape the data. Here, we actually don't need to use Selenium as the data is already baked right into the HTML when we go to the webpage.

```
%pip install -q curl_cffi
%pip install -q fake-useragent
%pip install -q lxml

from curl_cffi import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
# we need to take care for this: https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/

ua = UserAgent()    
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.safari}
resp = requests.get('https://clutch.co/pt/it-services', headers=headers, impersonate="safari15_3")
resp.status_code


# I like to use this to verify the contents of the request
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(resp.text)

from lxml.html import fromstring

tree = fromstring(resp.text)

data = []

for company in tree.xpath('//ul/li[starts-with(@id, "provider")]'):
    data.append({
        "name": company.xpath('./@data-title')[0].strip(),
        "location": company.xpath('.//span[@class = "locality"]')[0].text,
        "wage": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Avg. hourly rate</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "min_project_size": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Min. project size</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "employees": company.xpath('.//div[@data-content = "<i>Employees</i>"]/span/text()')[0].strip(),
        "description": company.xpath('.//blockquote//p')[0].text,
        "website_link": (company.xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "website-link__item")]/@href') or ['Not Available'])[0],
    })


import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(data, max_level=0)
df
```

At the moment I wonder why the xpath on the website does not give back some more results. I guess that I have to do a better defining of this tiny part of the script - and to write a proper path towards this entity.

Comment: you have to add some data to the script - see this line with the headers = {
    "User-Agent": - but hmm - i am not sure what to add here at this line - and in googlecolab... 
perhaps others may here helpful - and can provide a answr

Comment: the website you're trying to scrap from probably has some sort of anti-bot protection, hence your scrapper are not extracting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you're trying to scrap from probably has some sort of anti-bot protection with CloudFlare or similar services, hence your scrapper are not extracting anything. You need to use `selenium` with a headless browser like Headless Chrome or PhantomJS. Selenium automates a real browser, which can navigate Cloudflare's anti-bot pages just like a human user.

Here's how you should use `selenium` to imitate a real human browser interaction:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://clutch.co/il/it-services"
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Your scraping logic goes here
company_names = soup.select(".directory-list div.provider-info--header .company_info a")
locations = soup.select(".locality")

company_names_list = [name.get_text(strip=True) for name in company_names]
locations_list = [location.get_text(strip=True) for location in locations]

data = {"Company Name": company_names_list, "Location": locations_list}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index += 1
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql"))
df.to_csv("it_services_data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    | Company Name                                        | Location                       |
|----+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------|
|  1 | Artelogic                                           | L'viv, Ukraine                 |
|  2 | Iron Forge Development                              | Palm Beach Gardens, FL         |
|  3 | Lionwood.software                                   | L'viv, Ukraine                 |
|  4 | Greelow                                             | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
|  5 | Ester Digital                                       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
|  6 | Nextly                                              | Vitória, Brazil                |
|  7 | Rootstack                                           | Austin, TX                     |
|  8 | Opinov8 Technology Services                         | London, United Kingdom         |
|  9 | Scalo                                               | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 10 | TLVTech                                             | Herzliya, Israel               |
| 11 | Dofinity                                            | Bnei Brak, Israel              |
| 12 | PURPLE                                              | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 13 | Insitu S2 Tikshuv LTD                               | Haifa, Israel                  |
| 14 | Sogo Services                                       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 15 | Naviteq LTD                                         | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 16 | BMT - Business Marketing Tools                      | Ra'anana, Israel               |
| 17 | Profisea                                            | Hod Hasharon, Israel           |
| 18 | MeteorOps                                           | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 19 | Trivium Solutions                                   | Herzliya, Israel               |
| 20 | Dynomind.tech                                       | Jerusalem, Israel              |
| 21 | Madeira Data Solutions                              | Kefar Sava, Israel             |
| 22 | Titanium Blockchain                                 | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 23 | Octopus Computer Solutions                          | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 24 | Reblaze                                             | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 25 | ELPC Networks Ltd                                   | Rosh Haayin, Israel            |
| 26 | Taldor                                              | Holon, Israel                  |
| 27 | Clarity                                             | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 28 | Opsfleet                                            | Kfar Bin Nun, Israel           |
| 29 | Hozek Technologies Ltd.                             | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 30 | ERG Solutions                                       | Ramat Gan, Israel              |
| 31 | Komodo Consulting                                   | Ra'anana, Israel               |
| 32 | SCADAfence                                          | Ramat Gan, Israel              |
| 33 | Ness Technologies | נס טכנולוגיות                   | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 34 | Bynet Data Communications Bynet Data Communications | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 35 | Radware                                             | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 36 | BigData Boutique                                    | Rishon LeTsiyon, Israel        |
| 37 | NetNUt                                              | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 38 | Asperii                                             | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 39 | PractiProject                                       | Ramat Gan, Israel              |
| 40 | K8Support                                           | Bnei Brak, Israel              |
| 41 | Odix                                                | Rosh Haayin, Israel            |
| 42 | Panaya                                              | Hod Hasharon, Israel           |
| 43 | MazeBolt Technologies                               | Giv'atayim, Israel             |
| 44 | Porat                                               | Tel Aviv-Jaffa, Israel         |
| 45 | MindU                                               | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 46 | Valinor Ltd.                                        | Petah Tikva, Israel            |
| 47 | entrypoint                                          | Modi'in-Maccabim-Re'ut, Israel |
| 48 | Adelante                                            | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 49 | Code n' Roll                                        | Haifa, Israel                  |
| 50 | Linnovate                                           | Bnei Brak, Israel              |
| 51 | Viceman Agency                                      | Tel Aviv-Jaffa, Israel         |
| 52 | develeap                                            | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
| 53 | Chalir.com                                          | Binyamina-Giv'at Ada, Israel   |
| 54 | WolfCode                                            | Rishon LeTsiyon, Israel        |
| 55 | Penguin Strategies                                  | Ra'anana, Israel               |
| 56 | ANG Solutions                                       | Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel          |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: hello dear Musabbir Arrafi - many thanks for all. This is very encouraging. 

question: can i use  selenium to imitate a real human browser interaction - on google colab too? see my results: https://pastebin.com/FpEDLNiA

look at the colab page:  colab.research.google.com/drive/1WilnQwzDq45zjpJmgdjoyU5wTVAgJqvd#scrollTo=pyd0BcMaPxkJ - i really look forward to hear from you again... - many thanks in advance

btw: we are allmost there ;)

Comment: again me  - could it be a issue on selenium on Colab - see here: 
Selenium use chrome on Colab got unexpectedly exited
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155063/selenium-use-chrome-on-colab-got-unexpectedly-exited

well i woul love to see you on my google-colab-account - that shows the issue ... (see above) 
have a great day ;)

Comment: good evening dar Musabbir Arrafi 

many thanks - your so great and your explanations are awesome! This forum is a awesome place to be!

i now run a tiny modified parser that works well  - but at a certain point it lacks some precision: see below:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F3cDTaumFyXj1o3k_i-1mOzIOZBn8KsH?usp=sharing
well  at the moment i wonder why the xpath on the "Website" does not give back some more results.guess that i have to do a better defining of this tiny part of the script - and to write a propper path  towards this entity!?Any idea